# Where does the OS store the command line arguments?

Tags: c

I am working on Linux. In which section of memory are the command line arguments stored (stack or heap)?

I tried to execute `free(argv)` and I got a segmentation fault. Why is that?

Comment: I would assume that they are stored on the stack (before main is called) so you shouldn't really be messing with their memory!

Comment: why does it matter? and why don't you check the address? :/

Comment: @yi_H: How can I infer the section by address?

Comment: @yi_H - it matters to an inquisitive mind. Good beginners should ask these kind of questions all the time. Documentation may be too dry in this matter so one has to turn to a mentor.

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera: it was a rhetorical question. Maybe it's true for beginners, but professionals has to know where to draw the line.. modern computer systems are way too complicated to know every small detail. as long as it doesn't matter what's the point of knowing it?

Comment: @yi_H - agree that systems may be too complex to know every little detail. This, however, is general knowledge and it is needed if you dwell in C enough time. The same can be said for, example, garbage collection methods when you are working with Java.

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera: yes, you might need to know that Java GC can take a lot of time and can hinder near-realtime systems, and that there is an alternative GC to solve such a problem. but can you give me just *one* example where knowing where argv is stored gives you *any* usable knowledge / benefit? does that matter at all from a C pointer's perspective?

Comment: @yi_H: I concede you have a point knowing the specific place where argv is stored may be of little use. I still disagree with the "don't see, doesn't matter" sentiment so prevalent these days. Inquisitive minds need to know!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are C/C++ main function's parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196201/where-are-c-c-main-functions-parameters)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I tried to execute free(argv) and I got a segmentation fault. Why is that?

You can only `free` what you `malloc`/`calloc` (and possibly `realloc` later on). Trying to `free` something else invokes Undefined Behaviour. One (good) way UB manifests itself is by producing a segmentation fault; a (bad) way is to make the program appear to work as intended.

As to where they are ... read section 5.1.2.2.1 of the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) -- its **unspecified**.

> the strings pointed to by the argv array shall
>   be modiﬁable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
>   startup and program termination.

Comment: @Bruce: so `argv` points somewhere, you never know and must not rely upon.

Comment: `argv` points to a groups of pointers. Each of the pointers `argv` points to reside where the compiler puts them (you can try to read the source of your compiler or ask the developers). Each of the things pointed to by the pointers in `argv` reside where the compiler put them.

Comment: @pmg: Please someone tell me where argv points to. Its killing me.

Comment: @Bruce: we've *been* telling you, it's up to the individual compiler.  It could be the stack, the heap, or a completely different memory segment.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` / `int main(int argc, char **argv) { printf("%p\n", (void*)argv); return 0; }` results in `0x7fff0a8a9318`. That's where `argv` points to: **0x7fff0a8a9318** Remember this :)

Comment: @All: I am using gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)

Comment: Argv typically is located on (or near) the stack though. Anything stored in the stack area not either explicitly initialized by you (uninitialized vars, say) or used for control purposes (the location the stack keeps its ebp or esp, say) will be garbage: some number that could be anything, and, when used as a memory location as you use it in free(), could thus point anywhere. This is only in response to where it points. What happens when you free() stuff not priorly malloc()ed has been answered already.

Comment: This is a painfully unhelpful answer. You don't actually answer the question, just berate the asker for daring to ask.

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on Linux. In which section of memory are the command line arguments stored (stack or heap)?

That's up to the implementation; check your compiler documentation.  All that's required is that that `argc` and `argv`, as well as the strings that the `argv` array points to, be modifiable by the program.

> I tried to execute `free(argv)` and I got a segmentation fault. Why is that?

You didn't allocated `argv` with `malloc`.  You don't need to free the command line argument vectory.