# Pointer or array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I know that pointers are a lot like arrays (if not one and the same) in a way, but I'm having trouble deciphering when I should explicitly delete a pointer.

Take this code for example:

```
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<char*> strings;

    strings.push_back(argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Now obviously, no one in their right mind would make a program exactly like this, but for pure discussion, let's say this is my program. Should I have deleted `strings.at(0)` to avoid a memory leak there, or is the data considered a character array to be destroyed when the program terminates?

Similarly, suppose I have a `vector` of a class I've created, and I've declared them all as `new` instances of the class. Do I then need to delete, or is it fine?

I'm a self-taught programmer, so these complicated (and sometimes dangerous) concepts make me paranoid.

Comment: You've been badly misinformed; pointers and arrays are not *at all* the same thing. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); it applies to C++ as well.

Comment: As a self-taught programmer interested in memory management, I believe you should take a look (if you haven't already) at how smart pointers work in C++11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variable -> allocated on `stack` -> gets destroyed automatically when function exits.
Dynamically allocated variables -> allocated on `heap` -> need to `delete` them after use.

If you have a program that runs non-stop, say some daemon/background process. And you allocated a lot of dynamic variables using `new` and you do that frequently in your code. Then, with time the memory requirement of your running program will increase since you are not deleting them, to a point that you are no more able to allocate more memory.

And if, it's a small program that exits, the OS generally reclaims the memory, but it's the job of the programmer to not to leave it to the OS to reclaim the memory.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule, you should `free` or `delete` anything you `malloc` or `new`.

With the `vector`, when you push into a vector, it does a copy.  So a copy of a pointer just copies the address that the pointer points to, not the actual data pointed to.

To answer your question, you should not free `argv[0]` since you didn't malloc it - see [Where does the OS store the command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728191/where-does-the-os-store-the-command-line-arguments) for an explanation.

If you `new` your own class, then you should delete the entries in the vector and then clear it (per Claudiordgz's answer).

**EDIT** since the answer was deleted, you can do something like:

```
for(auto it = strings.begin(); it != strings.end(); ++it)
{
  delete *it;
}
strings.clear()
```

(direct copy from the referenced answer)