# i wonder about linux memory alignment and layout

Tags: linux, memory, fedora

two strange looks from the code example below does not make sense.

1. Why is the distance between `foo` and `argv[0]` is always different?
2. Why are not aligned to 4? Although the expected result is a multiple of 4 and does not

I would like to know the detailed reasons for the strange looks.

and i know it is not relate with [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)
[root@localhost ~]# cat poc.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int foo;
    printf("%d\n",  (int)argv[0] - (int)&foo);
}
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5345
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
8465
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
4641
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
1201
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
2881
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
7073
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5905
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
2225
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
2465
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
6017
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
8657
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
8401
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5073
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5505
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
1761
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
8609
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3665
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3633
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
6257
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3441
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
4961
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5233
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
561
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3441
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
2097
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
1729
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
1841
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
2241
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
2145
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
6593
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5681
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
737
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
8353
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
1937
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3937
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
4769
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3441
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
6097
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
6673
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
1857
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5617
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5473
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
7313
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3921
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
2369
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
4609
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5569
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
6209
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3457
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3665
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3297
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
4465
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5281
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
6017
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
2705
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
1601
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
7457
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
4145
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
2353
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
5537
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
7873
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
6449
[root@localhost ~]# ./poc
3297
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why is the distance between foo and argv[0] is always different?**

Because of ASLR.

> and i know it is not relate with ASLR

Are you sure about that? What is your kernel's virtual addresses space randomization parameter value (randomize_va_space) ? It should be 0.

**2. Why are not aligned to 4? Although the expected result is a multiple of 4 and does not**

What do you want to demonstrate with that? Your code computes the distance from the first string in **argv** to the local variable **foo**. What's the point of this?

How & where parameters and local variables are handled is really OS and compilers dependent. Have a look at the following post : [Where are C/C++ main functions parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196201/where-are-c-c-main-functions-parameters)