# In which memory segment command line arguments get stored?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

The command line arguments `argc`, `arv[]`, used with the `main` function in C, where do they get stored in memory?

The storage area I am looking for this question should be heap, data segment, stack or other.

Comment: I think it was similar question with answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196201/where-are-c-c-main-functions-parameters:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18681093/15168), the C language does not define where the command line arguments must be stored, and there isn't much practical use to knowing.  However, the information is normally stored on the stack.

This code uses a common extension to the `main()` to get hold of the environment too, and then prints the addresses of both the arguments and the environment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    printf("&argc = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)&argc);
    printf("&argv = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)&argv);
    printf("&envp = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)&envp);
    while (*argv != 0)
        printf("*argv = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)*argv++);
    while (*envp != 0)
        printf("*envp = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)*envp++);
    return 0;
}
```

When run on my Mac, it showed:

```
&argc = 0x7FFF5494B52C
&argv = 0x7FFF5494B520
&envp = 0x7FFF5494B518
*argv = 0x7FFF5494B748
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B74E
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B839
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B862
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B86D
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B889
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B8C1
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B8F4
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B905
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B915
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B920
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B92E
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B93B
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B974
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B998
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B9CD
*envp = 0x7FFF5494B9F2
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BA0B
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BA2A
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BA46
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BA7B
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BB2E
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BB3C
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BB76
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BB87
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BB9D
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BBC8
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BBEA
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BC2B
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BC35
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BC51
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BC5F
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BC75
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BC82
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BD55
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BD7E
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BD96
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BDA3
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BDAE
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BDBF
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BDCA
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BDE8
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BE01
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BE09
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BE1E
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BE38
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BE52
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BE71
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BE7D
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BEF5
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BF16
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BF27
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BF32
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BF66
*envp = 0x7FFF5494BF8D
```

That's pretty unexciting, but shows that all the addresses are in the same general area, which is the C stack.  (Tested on Mac OS X 10.8.4 — 64-bit program, invoked without any command line arguments and a biggish environment.)

Comment: but `argc` is not a constant and `argv` is a pointer to string literals. Does the stack frame for `main` varies, based on how many command line arguments are passed?

Comment: Usually, yes — the stack frame depends on the number of arguments passed.  It can also depend on the size of the environment (the collection of environment variables).  But it all depends on the implementation.  Both `argc` and `argv` are ordinary local variables that can be modified.  They are initialized carefully by the system, though, and convey useful information to the program.  And no, `argv` points to initialized strings, but they're not string literals.

Answer (score 3):

It's not specified by the language.

Unix-like systems put them on the stack (or in the case of some of the more esoteric systems, "a" stack, since they have more than one).