# what is the purpose of argc and argv?

Tags: c++, c

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv ){
//code here
 return 0; }
```

I know that:

1. `argc` is indicates the number of command line arguments including the file name
2. `char ** argv` is supposed to be a `char*` to an array which was initially represented as `char* argv[]`

Assuming I am right what is with the relatively new notation `char **argv` compared to `char * argv[]`? What does it point to?

I read this post
[Where are C/C++ main function's parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196201/where-are-c-c-main-functions-parameters) however it seems to explain where the arguments are and nothing else.

Comment: They are actually equal

Comment: `char **argv and char * argv[]?` are equal.

Comment: @Jayesh, in parameters of a function declaration, yes.

Comment: @user2079303 yes..as a parameter are same.

Comment: @Jayesh, ooh, I thought you were commenting on the previous comment, asking if they're equal :) Apparently the question mark isn't at the end as I first thought.

Comment: "Relatively new"? It's probably older than you are...

Comment: @user2079303 I thought you missed `?` :) that's why....

Comment: @Jayesh: That `?` shouldn't be there anyway.

Comment: i compared it to the other notation  
hence the word "relatively"  
this makes me curious about how old is it anyways i know its not important still?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `main` prototype with parameters in the C Standard is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }
```

Now in C a function parameter of type array is *adjusted* <sup>1)</sup> to a type pointer, that is:

```
void foo(T param[])
```

is equivalent to

```
void foo(T *param)
```

so using `char *argv[]` or `char **argv` for the `main` parameter is exactly the same.

---

<sub>1) (C99, 6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) p15) "[...] (In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)"</sub>

Comment: i read somewhere that in c the main function be called from anywhere in the program. is this true? how will it work?

Answer (score 3):

In C/C++ you can't pass an array by value to a function. A pointer to array or its reference can be passed. When used as function parameter the array type is equivalent to pointer type, i.e

```
void foo(int arr[]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void foo(int *arr);
```

Similarly `int *argv[]` is equivalent to `int **argv`.
But note that this is true only when array types are used as parameter of a function otherwise   array and pointers are two different type.

Comment: say i have two functions 
    fun(char*)// this is actually an array  
    fun(char*)//this is a pointer  when i call these functions how will the compiler resolve the function calls?

Comment: You cannot overload on `char[]` and `char*` parameters. Just try it, the compiler will complain.

Comment: @Denson; Do you mean `fun(char [])` and `fun(char *)`?

Comment: @haccks that is what i meant  
 but as you pointer out both are equivalent as function parameters

Comment: i guess they cannot be overloaded as @FredOverflow pointed out.

Comment: @Denson; I updated my answer. Read first and second line.