# Memory allocation and **argv argument

Tags: c++, c, program-entry-point, argv

I know for what we use this argument, and I even know how to work with the argument.

There is only one things I still do not understand. How a program allocate memory for strings which came from the input. **argv has no allocated memory at the start of the program, isn't it? I was expecting segfault, but it didn't happen.

Does anybody know how this memory allocation work?

Comment: the what what?  huh?

Comment: What do you mean by "has no allocated memory"?  The pointers in `argv` are all valid and point to memory that's safe to access.  What code did you expect to produce a segfault?

Comment: It's allocated by the runtime library before `main()` is called.

Comment: possible duplicate?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196201/where-are-c-c-main-functions-parameters

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C/C++ runtime processes the command line arguments and creates an area of memory where the arguments are put.  It then calls your `main()` providing you a count of the number of arguments along with a pointer to the area where the arguments are stored.

So the C/C++ runtime owns the memory area allocated and it is up to the C/C++ runtime to deallocate the area once your `main()` returns or if some other C/C++ function is used to stop the program such as `exit()`.

This procedure originated with the use of C under Unix and was kept for C++ as a part of providing the degree of backwards compatibility the C++ committee has tried to maintain.

Normally when your program loads, the entry point that is started by the loader is not your `main()` function but rather an entry point defined in the C/C++ runtime.  The C/C++ runtime does various kinds of initialization to setup the environment that the C/C++ standards say will exist at the point when the `main()` function is called by the C/C++ runtime once the initialization is completed.

One of the steps during this initialization is the parsing of command line arguments provided which are then provided to the `main()` function as its function arguments.